# Is there a rubber type glue that sets in under 5 minutes?

Tags: adhesive, polyurethane

I'm looking for a very strong glue, similar to sikaflex 227

> Sika Sikaflex 227 Polyurethane Sealant Black is a one component, moisture curing, elastic adhesive/sealant that is used for waterproofing and sealing exterior seams, joints, and substrates such as plastics, metal, wood, steel, and aluminum. It is non-sagging, fast curing, odorless, fast-skinning, and non-staining.

so it's not actually billed as a “glue”, but it holds very tight but is also flexible.
I'm looking for a glue that cures flexible, holds very strong, and cures very quickly (minutes, not hours). I don't know if something like this exists, but I'm hoping.

Answer (score 0):

Flexible epoxies exist. Search for that.

Comment: This: https://www.permabond.com/products/flexible-adhesives/ looks like it could be a possibility. Since my last project was ruined by the glue, I can probably use the ruined pieces to test with before settling on something.